# What is the size of a boolean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

What is the size of a boolean data type in Ruby? There was a long discussion on [Ruby Forum](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4419629) regarding this, but there was no final answer that I could get from it.

Also, how can I find what size it is.

For example if I stored it in an array, how much memory would it take

```
a=[true, true]
```

vs

```
a=[1,1]
```

Comment: You really, *really* shouldn't care about this in Ruby. It doesn't matter. Choose the data type most appropriate for the data you're trying to store.

Comment: If you're actually using `1` (and not `4000`), they're each a byte of memory.

Comment: I am doing some work with data structures and studying Bit Vectors

Comment: @Coreyward, could you elaborate how only one byte is needed to store `1` (and presumably other small integers)?

Comment: @coreyward: I'm pretty sure they're all `VALUE`s internally and that's the same size as a native pointer.

Comment: @muistooshort, `VALUE` is a c pointer to hold the reference to an object. There are 3 pointers (one for `a`, another two for two inner objs), and there are additional memories allocated for the content of the 3 objects.

Comment: @huocp: Some `VALUE`s are immediate (such as `1`, `nil`, `true`, `false`, ...). There is only one `1`, it is a specific pointer sized sequence of bytes; similarly for `true`. So `[1,1]`, `[true, true]`, `[0,true]`, `[nil, 11]` should all be the same size. A `VALUE` isn't always a pointer.

Comment: @muistooshort, thx. I don't know about this in Ruby, similar to what Obj-C and Swift does.

Comment: You can test this yourself, if you are so inclined. Test memory usage, initialize an array of N entries of the relevant types, and test memory usage again. If it quacks like a duck…

Comment: @coreyward that's a good idea, I will try testing memory usage. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Serializing tells us that

```
Marshal.dump([true,true]).length # => 6
Marshal.dump(true).length # => 3

Marshal.dump([1,1]).length # => 8
Marshal.dump(1).length # => 4
```

I'm pretty sure that this values does not represent real memory usage, but `[true,true]` seems to be more effective than `[1,1]`.

Answer (score 1):

The Ruby Language Specification does not specify any particular representation for any object. Every Ruby Implementation is free to choose any representation it wants.

Note also that not being able to tell the representation of an object is the *defining* characteristic of Object-Oriented Data Abstraction. If it *were* possible to tell the size of a `Boolean`, Ruby wouldn't be object-oriented!